# How to copy rows from one sheet to another based on criteria in column-- paste only values and formatting (not formulas)?

Tags: excel, vba

This code works as expected to copy the cells given a value of "xxx" in column B.
The issue is that it copies the entire row contents, including formulas. I would only like to copy the cell values and formatting, not formulas.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example (source sheet = sheet2)
   With Worksheets("Sheet2")
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'Message box to confirm how many rows were scanned to ensure all rows were scanned
   MsgBox ("Number of rows scanned: " & LastRow)


   'First row number where you need to paste values in Sheet3 (destination sheet = sheet3)'
   With Worksheets("Sheet3")
  j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
   With Worksheets("Sheet2")
       If .Cells(i, 2).Value = "xxx" Then
           .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & j)
           j = j + 1
       End If
   End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

I've tried amending the last portion to read like

```
       .Rows(i).Copy 
       .Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

However that attempts to paste the rows in the same worksheet (probably because it's under "With"). I haven't been able to change the destination of the pasting of the rows. Ideally I would like the copied rows to be pasted into Sheet3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copy pasting use value=value such that:

```
.Rows(j).value = .rows(i).value
```

For moving to another sheet, you could add the sheet reference and a lastrow:

```
sheets(3).rows(sheets(3).cells(sheets(3).rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0).row).value = .rows(i).value
```

**Edit1:**

Using your j...

```
sheets(3).rows(j).value = .rows(i).value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I fear I'm too ignorant in VBA to understand how to implement this into my code to get it working, though...could you please clarify which sections I should add the reference to the destination sheet to?

Comment: @Tester_Y  This would go in your loop, replacing the copy/paste line

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function FilterByTable(fromWs As Worksheet, destWs As Worksheet, tableFilter As String) As Boolean
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    'Assume false
    FilterByTable = False

    With fromWs
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'This gives the value for the last row in this range
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            'Looking for any row that meets this filter i.e. val=tableFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & tableFilter
            Set copyFrom = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With destWs
        'Some error checking since this will fail if you try to perform the operation on an empty data set
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If
        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
    FilterByTable = True
End Function
```